# Voltage calculation at any point between two plates at different voltage

Tags: electric-fields, voltage, distance

I have two plates (actually they are electrical connectors on a board) and I try to find the way of getting the $V$ value at any point between two plates, $A$ and $B$.

- A is at $V_o$ (in my case it is at $6 KV$) and B is at $V=0$.
- distance between $A$ and $B$ is $d$.
- At any point at $x$ distance from $A$.

1.- I know $E=-AV/d$ --> $V$ at any point $p$ ie. $V_p$= $-\int \vec{E}·\vec{dr}$

2.- I have found that between two plates: $$V(d) = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_od}$$

How can I use them for getting $V$ value at any distance $(x)$ between A and B conductors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore complicated edge effects, then the E-field between the two plates is constant, then the potential difference will change linearly between them. In practice, $E = \frac{V_0}{d_0}$ (where $V_0$ is the potential difference between the plates and $d_0$ is the distance between plates), is the slope of the potential difference as a function os distance from one of the plates.